# -[AVPlayerLayer setDisplayEngineDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2822fd6a0

Tags: ios, avplayer, facebook-ios-sdk, crash-reports, facebook-audience-network

Our iOS APP is connected to Facebook's advertising SDK (FBAudienceNetwork). Starting about two weeks ago (UTC+08 October 21, 2020), we discovered a new crash in the Firebase crash statistics background. Since the day before yesterday (UTC+08 November 2, 2020) the number of crashes has increased dramatically, and the situation seems to have gotten worse.

Below is the crash information:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[AVPlayerLayer setDisplayEngineDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2835f70e0

0  CoreFoundation                 0x19b1c9654 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x19aeebbcc objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x19b0cddd8 -[NSOrderedSet initWithSet:copyItems:]
3  CoreFoundation                 0x19b1cd7f8 ___forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation                 0x19b1cf71c _CF_forwarding_prep_0
5  MyAppName                      0x104725b18 -[FNFSynchronousPlayer initWithDisplayEngine:config:audioEngine:audioDecoder:clock:runningQueue:muted:asyncTimebase:] + 174 (FNFSynchronousPlayer.mm:174)
6  MyAppName                      0x10471e27c -[FNFPlayer initWithDisplayEngine:clock:config:asyncTimebase:enableOpus:] + 73 (FNFPlayer.mm:73)
7  MyAppName                      0x10471e0dc -[FNFPlayer initWithDisplayEngine:config:asyncTimebase:enableOpus:] + 46 (FNFPlayer.mm:46)
8  MyAppName                      0x10471e020 -[FNFPlayer initWithDisplayEngine:] + 39 (FNFPlayer.mm:39)
9  MyAppName                      0x1046f2eec __loadVideoAsset_block_invoke + 67 (FBAdFNFCompatibility.m:67)
10 MyAppName                      0x10473092c -[FNFLocalMp4Asset _startWithAsset:handler:outHandler:] + 301 (FNFLocalMp4Asset.mm:301)
11 MyAppName                      0x104732594 __53-[FNFLocalMp4Asset _loadAssetWithHandler:outHandler:]_block_invoke + 395 (FNFLocalMp4Asset.mm:395)
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x19ae8e9a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x19ae8f524 _dispatch_client_callout
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x19ae6cb3c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x19ae6d54c _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$armv81
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x19ae7684c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19aee0b74 _pthread_wqthread
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19aee3740 start_wqthread
```

Below is the Facebook-related information in the Podfile.lock file:

```
- FBAudienceNetwork (5.8.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit/Basics (>= 5.6.0)
- FBSDKCoreKit (5.6.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit/Basics (= 5.6.0)
    - FBSDKCoreKit/Core (= 5.6.0)
- FBSDKCoreKit/Basics (5.6.0)
- FBSDKCoreKit/Core (5.6.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit/Basics
- FBSDKLoginKit (5.6.0):
    - FBSDKLoginKit/Login (= 5.6.0)
- FBSDKLoginKit/Login (5.6.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.0)
- FBSDKShareKit (5.6.0):
    - FBSDKShareKit/Share (= 5.6.0)
- FBSDKShareKit/Share (5.6.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.0)
    - FBAudienceNetwork (= 5.8.0)
    - FBAudienceNetwork (~> 5.8.0)
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.6.0)
- FBSDKCoreKit (= 5.6.0)
- FBSDKLoginKit (= 5.6.0)
- FBSDKShareKit (= 5.6.0)
    - FBAudienceNetwork
    - FBSDKCoreKit
    - FBSDKLoginKit
    - FBSDKShareKit
FBAudienceNetwork: 98c125767300048ad46c756680644f4ecb7c4040
FBSDKCoreKit: d6655a343868d4bb5c29a60859bab07c3be14a0b
FBSDKLoginKit: c5a623de88a6b0cda35b35582921f6cec2efcc36
FBSDKShareKit: 0d8c4cfd5c1f185d5f9c26d79758b141086e1251
```

Comment: Starting at 12 o'clock noon yesterday (UTC+08 2020-11-05 12:00), the crash suddenly stopped appearing. Up to now (UTC+08 2020-11-06 12:39) there has been no such crash.
The problem seems to have disappeared. I don't know if it is the adjustment of Facebook's internal dynamic configuration.
I will continue to observe the situation of this issue.

Comment: Since last Friday (UTC+08 2020-11-06 12:39), the crash has reappeared, and the trend has been increasing rapidly. This problem has not disappeared.
Later we should try to update FBAudienceNetwork to see if this problem can be solved.